# Padding underscore with right space

Tags: fonts, symbols, characters, kerning, times

I am using the `times` package and when using an underscore `_` before an italicized upper case character it overlaps. Is it possible to pad the underscore with a small amount of space to the right, or shift it slightly to the left? It is not an issue using other fonts (e.g. utopia), but I want to use `times` for the document.

[image: underscore_position]

Comment: As always, it would be great that you provide us with the actual code to produce your example (starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`).

Comment: `\textit{T\_{\hskip0.02em L}}` as a quick trial, but I would rather mind the strange look of `T_L` regarding the spacing between `T` and `_`

Comment: textit had no effect. Is there a particular place in the document that it needs to be declared?

Comment: A rare ligature, maybe? :)

Comment: Well, you wrote italicized, so I assumed, that you have applied `\textit` or `\itshape`  (or the oldfashioned `\it`).

Comment: I see. Is it possible to replace every occurrence automatically?

Comment: perhaps in the style file? my ligatures are in an environment called 'zed', so would that be an option?

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but did you read 
`The pack­age is now ob­so­lete, re­placed by the math­ptmx pack­age, which sup­ports Times Ro­man text and (mostly) match­ing math­e­mat­ics.` on  http://www.ctan.org/pkg/times?

Comment: What about looking around the site for kerning? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112287/difference-between-mskip-and-mkern

Comment: I've updated to use ptmx, but the underscore issue is still a problem. Replacing one occurrence with the \textit macro solved the formatting issue, but I need the document to contain "\_" so that other tools can parse it. This makes me think I need some global replacement for '\_' that happens when the pdf is generated

Comment: In my style file, I have 
\def\_{\leavevmode \ifmmode\else\kern0.16em R\fi \vbox{\hrule
    width0.5em}} - could I change this to solve the kerning issue?

Comment: possible solution given as an answer where (as in my case) it's possible to edit the style file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep the underscore character vertically aligned with the surrounding characters, I added the following definition to the style file:

```
\def\_{\leavevmode \ifmmode\else\kern0.16em R\fi \vbox{\hrule
    width0.5em}\tiny\ \normalsize}
```

This did the trick:

[image: padded underscore]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%% Should be loaded
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\textit{T\_L}
\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
\textit{T\_L}    
\end{document}
```

[image]