# How can I typeset the included diagram in xymatrix?

Tags: arrows, parallel, xymatrix

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lastpage}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex  

\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\normalfont % in case the EC fonts aren't available
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
Given categories $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{B}$ consider the natural transformations:
$\xymatrix{\mathbb{A}\ar@<2ex>[r]^F^{\alpha} \ar[r]_G \ar@<-2ex>[r]_H^{\beta}&\mathbb{B}}$ 
\end{document}$
```

Please help me typeset this arrow diagram in xymatrix. This is vertical composition of two natural transformations.

[image: Vertical Composition of two natural transformations1]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: $\xymatrix{\mathbb{A}\ar@<-2ex>[r]^F_{\alpha} \ar[r]^G} \ar@<2ex>[r]_H}&\mathbb{B}$

Comment: You should edit your question, and to include in it a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: I am new here, i don't know what you mean.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Can I include the .tex file i am working on?

Comment: I am afraid that then the example would not be minimal.

Comment: Please show me exactly what i need to do because the contents of the link you provided was also quite a mouthful.

Comment: Edit your question and include in it the code for a working LaTeX file which contains your attempt.

Comment: How does this look?

Comment: What you have posted cannot be compiled.

Comment: Sorry, i have fixed it.

Comment: No, you have not. Where is the document class. Where is the `\begin{document}`? Where is the `\end{document}`? Do you really believe that what you wrote is a complete LaTeX document that can be compiled?

Comment: This compiles on my side.

Comment: I have edited your question.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I know you requested a solution with `xy`, but you may want to consider a `tikz-cd` solution.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=.3cm, column sep=3cm]
\phantom{\mathbb{A}}\arrow[r, "F" description, ""{name=top, below}] & \phantom{\mathbb{B}}\\
\mathbb{A}\arrow[r,"G" description, ""{name=midtop, above}, ""{name=midbot, below}] & \mathbb{B}\\
\phantom{\mathbb{A}}\arrow[r, "H" description, ""{name=bot}] & \phantom{\mathbb{B}}
\arrow[from=top,to=midtop,"\alpha"]
\arrow[from=midbot,to=bot,"\beta"]
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

The idea is to `name` the space above and below the center labels so that the vertical arrows can be placed correctly. The `\phantom` symbols are used to keep the horizontal arrows the same length.

You can adjust the spacing to your liking by changing `row sep` and `column sep` values.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated 1**: Using an hacky.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=.8pc@C=8pc{
\mathbb{A}  \ar[r]|G  \ar@<-4ex>[r]_H \ar@<4ex>[r]^F_{\mkern9.8mu\big\downarrow \alpha} \ar@<10.5ex>[d]^{\beta} &\mathbb{B}\\
      &
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I'm not very able with the explanations but it not necessary to use double dollars `$` with `\xymatrix` as from my example, that is similar to the original image. My code it is very simple because I'm not an expert (for my low level to understand the documentations) and you can see the minimal differences.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[all]{xy}


\begin{document}

\xymatrix@1@C=6pc{
\ar[r]^F \ar@<7.9ex>[d]^{\alpha}&\\
\mathbb{A} \ar[r]|G \ar@<7.9ex>[d]^{\beta}& \mathbb{B}\\
\ar[r]_H & 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here there is a different approaches for the rows `R` and the columns `C`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[all]{xy}


\begin{document}
xymatrix@R=1pc@C=5pc{
\ar[r]^F \ar@<7.2ex>[d]^{\alpha}&\\
\mathbb{A} \ar[r]|G \ar@<7.2ex>[d]^{\beta}& \mathbb{B} \\
\ar[r]_H & 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sebastiano thank you, this is exactly what i wanted. My problem was adding the arrows pointing down. However, i see that you used 6 nodes in total. Just for the fun of it, is it possible to have achieved it using only two nodes?

Comment: I just noticed that in your solution the arrow G is shorter than the other two.

Comment: @SifisoMasuku I'm glad to help you. I'm thinking but peraphs it is impossible. It is true but with a lot of sincerity I think that is the label G that is above the first vertical arrow. Peraphs I will must shift the arrow....also to have 4 nodes in the total.

Comment: @SifisoMasuku I have done an updating.

Comment: This is excellent, well done. Thank you very much.

Comment: where did you learn about \mkern so quickly and how does it work?

Comment: @SifisoMasuku `\mkern` is a mathematical command to shift a symbol: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112287/difference-between-mskip-and-mkern